# PySpark as a runtime for Django instead of a regular Python env?

Tags: python, django, apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to use PySpark as a runtime for Django instead of a regular python environment?

Since Django is just running Python tasks, could these tasks not be parallelized in Spark?

Here in `python3 manage.py shell_plus --notebook`, I have imported `pyspark` and ran a query using the ORM. It runs clean.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
import pyspark.sql

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="Django")
patients = Patient.nodes.all()
print(patients)
sc.stop()

[1]: #returned the data from my model
```

Or would this be a matter of triggering `runserver` from within pyspark?

```
$ pyspark
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir(r"/Users/me/Project")
>>> import manage
>>> print(manage)
<module 'manage' from '/Users/me/Project/manage.py'>
```

Comment: I suppose this would work for other Python MVC frameworks like Flask and Pyramid, maybe the Java frameworks like Grails and Spring too?

Answer (score 0):

`pyspark` is only a script to initialize all environment variables, Spark session; allow you to run your spark interactively. Overall there is no problem to run different python lib from pyspark shell

I don't know the reason behind your requirement, but the approach with pyspark only recommended on development not for production.

Comment: Could you please highlight more , why not pyspark use in Production.

Comment: To be precise, it is not recommended to use pyspark interaction in production. I suppose you asked above question and only use it in development